# Correcting for multiple comparisons between two sets of paired groups

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I am looking for the most appropriate correction for multiple comparisons in this situation. For two classes A and B we have N groups, for example:

```
A = {1: [1,2,3,4,5 ...],
     2: [5,2,4,4,9 ...],
     ...}
B = {1: [10,20,30,40,50 ...],
     2: [22,32,45,56,11 ...],
     ...}
```

The comparisons will then be between the means of A1 *vs* B1, A2 *vs* B2, and so on. The elements in the respective Ai and Bi series are not paired.

Right now I am simply using t-tests for each comparison and then applying Bonferroni's correction, but I am wondering whether there would be a more appropriate strategy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Bonferroni is that you won't detect any violations of the null hypothesis if $N$ is becoming large.

Thus, instead of asking for one test that covers everything, you should change your goal a bit: e.g.  the [Benjamini–Hochberg procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Controlling_procedures) answers the following question, which might be useful for you:

Which tests, out of my complete set of $N$ tests, should I consider to significantly reject the null hypothesis, if I want to have only a ratio of $q$ of those to be wrong, for some $q$ that the user can provide?

E.g., if you choose $q=0.1$, then the Benjamini–Hochberg procedure (BH) gives you those tests out of your total $N$ tests that are the most significant ones. Let's say (BH) returns e.g. $k=50$ such tests to you. Then BH makes sure that on average only $q\cdot k=0.1\cdot 50=5$ of those tests will be wrong.